# How do I import variables from a Python config file in a parent directory within a Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a repository with a handful of Python scripts (ETL jobs) that connect to various APIs (Google Analytics, Amazon, etc.). I'm using a virtual environment to keep track of dependencies when deploying this repo to a VPS instance.  I also have a `CONFIG.py` file with various API keys, database credentials, etc. (that I keep out of version control).

Just recently I needed to connect to the Google DFP API. There's a [known bug](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/110) that when you install the `googleads` library (using pip) it will install a newer version of the `oauth2client` library, which will break my Google Analytics API scripts because the `google-api-python-client` uses an older version of `oauth2client`.

So, to overcome this obstacle I'm considering creating a sub directory in my repo called, `Google_DFP` and creating a new virtual environment that uses the newer version of `oauth2client`.  Here is the new structure of my repo:

```
/ETL_Scripts
    CONFIG.py
    google_analytics.py
    google_search_console.py
    amazon_affiliate.py
    /venv
    /Google_DFP
      google_dfp.py
      /venv2
```

In my `google_analytics.py` file I use this to import the credentials `from CONFIG import DB_CREDENTIALS` and then use that object to connect to my database (username, password, etc.).

My question is: **how do I import variables out of the `CONFIG.py` file (in the parent directory) within the `google_dfp.py` file?**  When I attempt to import variables out of `CONFIG.py` -- `from ..CONFIG import DB_CREDENTIALS` -- I get this error: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Here's what my `CONFIG.py` file looks like:

```
AMAZON_API_KEY = "abcxyz123987"
DB_CREDENTIALS = {
    'database': 'fancy_reporting_db
    'user': 'etl_user',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'password': 'password'
}
```

Comment: Is your project a package? I don't see any `__init__.py`s... See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python/73149#73149).

Comment: This project is not a package.

Comment: Then you can't use relative imports. You can do something like `import sys; sys.path.append("/path/to/.../ETL_Scripts")` at the top of your `google_dpf.py` file. Obviously, you would use the actual path to the `ETL_Scripts` directory...